# PowerBI visuals How to call update on click event

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I develop the custom visuals.
I add click event on   element
And I want to call update manually update method (to refresh )
It worked when I use power bi online for developping
But it not work when package that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery in your custom visual to do that. In Simple terms see the below code. In this example I created an element then you can create a jQuery 'on' section to call the update method.

```
private $root: JQuery;
public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
  this.$root = $("#sandbox-host");   // Main container inside iframe of visual
  this.$root.append(`<div id="myElement" class="element"></div>`);

  $("#myElement").on("click", () => {
      this.update(this.options);
    });
}
```

Make sure to use => operator with "click" as it will give you "this" access of Class.

Second, don't forget to add jQuery libs in your dependencies of package.json. Add them and run npm install.

```
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"@types/jquery": "^2.0.41",
```

Once done, you can use jQuery in your visual.ts and other files.

Note - You can also add checks in your update() method using if conditions so you only execute required code on manually calling update() method.